# Technical term for hash value being uncorrelated to input message?

Tags: hash, random-number-generator, collision-resistance, randomness, pseudo-random-generator

Is there a technical term for the desirable property of hash functions. That a small change to the input message will produce a massive unpredictable and seemingly uncorrelated change to the output hash value? I keep getting stuck on words like pseudo-random and unpredictable but they don't seem to fit the property correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That a small change to the input message will produce a massive
>   unpredictable and seemingly uncorrelated change to the output hash
>   value?

It sounds like you're looking for the [*avalanche effect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect).

Answer (score 1):

For cryptographic hash functions, a hash function with this property is said to model a [random oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle). If a hash function can be instantiated with a key that may make it a [PRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family)

Crypto and non-crypto hash functions can exhibit the [avalanche effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect). A function modeling a random oracle means it has the avalanche effect, but not the reverse. "Avalanche" may just mean small changes will on average make big changes to output.

People don't necessarily define avalanche effect to require output changes to be highly unpredictable under scrutiny. It could just mean related input strings don't seem to produce related hash outputs for an ordinary computer science definition of hash functions. (ie. just for use in hash tables and no one trying to exploit the hash algorithm)

Edit:

You might say "SHA-512 can be treated as a random oracle" or "HMAC-SHA-256 is a PRF".